# Problem JSON Object /array in flutter <String, dynamic> is not subtype of <dynamic>

Tags: flutter

Hello i cannot parse the data from my api being a Json Object due to {} and then display it..

```
 {
  "id": 13805,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "status": "return-requested",
  "currency": "EUR",
  "version": "5.9.1",
  "prices_include_tax": true,
  "date_created": "2022-04-15T17:15:33",
  "date_modified": "2022-04-22T19:09:43",
  "discount_total": "0.00",
  "discount_tax": "0.00",
  "shipping_total": "5.99",
  "shipping_tax": "1.20",
  "cart_tax": "16.67",
  "total": "107.19",
  "total_tax": "17.87",
  "customer_id": 3,
  "order_key": "wc_order_AQMDdB8ctviru",
  "payment_method": "cod",
  "payment_method_title": "Paiement à la livraison",
  "transaction_id": "",
 
  "created_via": "checkout",
  "customer_note": "",
  "date_completed": "2022-04-22T00:59:57",
  "date_paid": "2022-04-16T01:31:27",
  "cart_hash": "2383a28954768eb32f9e5f4ca537bad3",
  "number": "13805",
  "meta_data": [
 
    {
      "id": 30472,
      "key": "is_vat_exempt",
      "value": "no"
    },
    {
      "id": 30473,
      "key": "_shipping_data",
      "value": [
        {
          "id": "local_pickup:1",
          "method_id": "local_pickup",
          "instance_id": 1,
          "label": "Point de vente",
          "cost": 0,
          "taxes": [
            
          ],
          "package_key": 3
        },
        {
          "id": "lpc_relay",
          "method_id": "lpc_relay",
          "instance_id": 25,
          "label": "Colissimo relais",
          "cost": 4.99,
          "taxes": {
            "1": 0.998
          },
          "package_key": 3
        },
 
        {
          "id": "wc-shipping-radius-0-3",
          "method_id": "wc-shipping-radius",
          "instance_id": 0,
          "label": "StreetDelivery",
          "cost": 11.8,
          "taxes": {
            "1": 2.36
          },
          "package_key": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 30475,
      "key": "_barcode_text",
      "value": "62598c1568688"
    },
    
    {
      "id": 30486,
      "key": "_wcfmd_delvery_times",
      "value": {
        "3": "1650114000|1650117600"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 30492,
      "key": "_wcfm_new_order_notified",
      "value": "yes"
    },
    {
      "id": 30493,
      "key": "_wcfm_membership_order_processed",
      "value": "yes"
    },
   
    {
      "id": 30495,
      "key": "_wcpdf_invoice_date",
      "value": "1650035733"
    },
    {
      "id": 30496,
      "key": "_wcpdf_invoice_date_formatted",
      "value": "2022-04-15 17:15:33"
    },
    {
      "id": 30497,
      "key": "_wcpdf_invoice_number",
      "value": "131"
    },
    {
      "id": 30498,
      "key": "_wcpdf_invoice_number_data",
      "value": {
        "number": 131,
        "formatted_number": "131",
        "prefix": "",
        "suffix": "",
        "document_type": "invoice",
        "order_id": 13805,
        "padding": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 30578,
      "key": "_wcfm_store_invoices",
      "value": {
        "3": "/home/u436579710/domains//public_html/wp-content/uploads/wcfm/vendor_invoice/2022/04/e71490137b17f3d1eb2e7298b2599a34/facture-000098.pdf"
      }
    }
  ],

  "barcode_url": "https:///?wc_barcode=62598c1568688",
  "currency_symbol": "€"
}
```

This is the code in vendor_admin.dart where the url is called and it is working fine in the app

```
  Future<List<OrderData>> getVendorAdminOrderdata(
      {int page = 1, int perPage = 10, String? orderId}) async {
    var list = <OrderData>[];
    try {
      var endpoint =
          '${serverConfig['url']}/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/$orderId/?consumer_key=${serverConfig['consumerKey']}&consumer_secret=${serverConfig['consumerSecret']}';
      final response = await httpGet(endpoint.toUri()!);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
        for (var item in result) {
          list.add(OrderData.fromJson(item));
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      printLog('vendor_admin.dart getVendorAdminOrderdata: $e');
    }
    return list;
  }
```

This is the file for the data order_data.dart

```
class OrderData {

  String? datePaidGmt;
  String? barcodeUrl;
  String? currencySymbol;

  OrderData({
        this.datePaidGmt,
        this.barcodeUrl,
        this.currencySymbol});



  factory OrderData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>? parsedJson) {
    switch (Config().type) {
      default:
        return OrderData._fromWooJson(parsedJson!);
    }
  }

  OrderData._fromWooJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    try {
      datePaidGmt = parsedJson['date_paid_gmt'];
      barcodeUrl = parsedJson['barcode_url'];
      currencySymbol = parsedJson['currency_symbol'];
    }catch (e, trace) {
      printLog(e.toString());
      printLog(trace.toString());
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['date_paid_gmt'] = this.datePaidGmt;
    data['barcode_url'] = this.barcodeUrl;
    data['currency_symbol'] = this.currencySymbol;
    return data;
  }
 }
```

This is how it is called as an action in the order_action.dart

```
    orderData = await _services.getVendorAdminOrderdata(
        page: page, perPage: _perPage, orderId: widget.order!.id);

    if (mounted) {
      // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

And this is how it is displayed in the needed screen order_detail_Screen.Dart

```
           Text(
                    widget.orderData!.barcodeUrl.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
              ),
```

FUll Code of the call on the screen :

```
 import'../../../models/order/order_data.dart';

part '../actions/order_item_details_actions.dart';

class VendorAdminOrderItemDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Order? order;
  final OrderData? orderData;
  final Function? onCallBack;
  final ProductItem? lineItem;
  final List<StoreDeliveryDate>? storeDeliveryDates;



  const VendorAdminOrderItemDetailsScreen(
      {Key? key, this.order, this.onCallBack,this.lineItem,this.orderData,this.storeDeliveryDates})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VendorAdminOrderItemDetailsScreenState createState() =>
      _VendorAdminOrderItemDetailsScreenState();
}

class _VendorAdminOrderItemDetailsScreenState
    extends State<VendorAdminOrderItemDetailsScreen> {
  final _noteController = TextEditingController();
  final fontSize = 16.0;
  final _services = injector<VendorAdminService>();
  final _perPage = 10;
  int page = 1;
  List<OrderNote> orderNotes = [];
  List<OrderData> orderData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchdata();
    _dropdownStatusValue = widget.order!.status;
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _getOrderNotes();
    });
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _getOrderData();
     });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final currencyRate =
        Provider.of<AppModel>(context, listen: false).currencyRate;
    final _addonsOptions = (widget.order!.addonsOptions ?? '')
        .split(', ')
        .map(Tools.getFileNameFromUrl)
        .join(', ');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          S.of(context).orderDetail,
          style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5,
        ),
        iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        actions: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () => setState(() {
              _enableEdit = !_enableEdit;
              if (!_enableEdit) {
                _cancelEdit();
              }
            }),
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                    !_enableEdit
                        ? S.of(context).editWithoutColon
                        : S.of(context).cancel,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _enableEdit
          ? InkWell(
              onTap: _updateOrder,
              child: Container(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 15.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  S.of(context).updateStatus,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Container(),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
               Text(
                    widget.orderData!.barcodeUrl.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
              ),
```

Any help will be welcome I've been stuck on it for a long time, I tried a lot of things without answers thank you.
Regards.

Comment: What does the API return, the content of response.body?

Comment: Yes it should be stored/get in the `final response` and then decode to be added to the List by what I understood.